Mailjet verification email fails, in c# gets 200 status but doesn't deliver, transactional messages null
I am writing an API in C# and am looking to use Mailjet. I have added the Mailjet package, my apiKey, and my secretKey to my .NET Core app. I added a domain and sender address to the site which seem to be valid. I configured the sender to have type "Unknown/Both".
I have tried a number of different things in code including trying different versions of the package.
First let me note that I tried to "Send your first email" via the Mailjet page: https://app.mailjet.com/auth/get_started/developer. I selected the sending method as "API" I first configured it to use C# and clicked on the "Verify Sending" button which resulted in a message:

We did not receive any successful feedbacks on the email sending. Please check the implementation of the code. Check our developers guide if you need help

Then I tried the "Python" and "Node.js" and I get the same error.
I have tried to send a Transactional email using the following code (from the github repo located here), and I get a result object back that has only one property named "Messages" which is null. (mymail@mydomain.com is a registered sender in the Mailjet interface)
MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient(apiKey, secretKey);

MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest
            {
                Resource = Send.Resource,
            };

// construct your email with builder
var email = new TransactionalEmailBuilder()
                   .WithFrom(new SendContact("mymail@mydomain.com"))
                   .WithSubject("Test subject")
                   .WithHtmlPart("<h1>Header</h1>")
                   .WithTo(new SendContact("mymail@mydomain.com"))
                   .Build();

// invoke API to send email
var response = await client.SendTransactionalEmailAsync(email);
Console.WriteLine(response);

I also tried what I think is sending a campaign email using the PostAsync function that is referenced on this site. Below is my code. When the PostAsync method completes, I get a 200 status code but Total and Count are both 0 and the Mailjet website shows no emails were sent.
MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient(apiKey, secretKey);

MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest
            {
                Resource = Send.Resource,
            }
            .Property(Send.FromEmail, "mymail@mydomain.com")
            .Property(Send.FromName, "Mailjet Pilot")
            .Property(Send.Subject, "Your email flight plan!")
            .Property(Send.TextPart, "Dear passenger, welcome to Mailjet! On this") 
            .Property(Send.Recipients, new JArray {
                new JObject {
                 {"Email", "mymail@mydomain.io"},
                 {"Name", "passenger 1"},
                 }
                });
            
MailjetResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total: {0}, Count: {1}\n", response.GetTotal(), response.GetCount()));
    Console.WriteLine(response.GetData());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("StatusCode: {0}\n", response.StatusCode));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ErrorInfo: {0}\n", response.GetErrorInfo()));
    Console.WriteLine(response.GetData());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ErrorMessage: {0}\n", response.GetErrorMessage()));
}

Am I doing something wrong in my code? Is this a configuration problem I need to fix in the site? How can I get more information about what is going on and how can I successfully send an email from my .NET Core app with Mailjet?
